# How can different file descriptors point to the same file in open file table?

Tags: linux, open-files, file-descriptors, table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can same fd in different processes point to the same file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28384/how-can-same-fd-in-different-processes-point-to-the-same-file)

I have a hard time grasping the two ideas of *File Descriptor Table* and *Open File Table*.

Open File Table is a table in kernel with all open files in the system, I understand that. However I don't understand the connection with the file descriptors.

[image]

If a *file descriptor* really is an **index** to a file then how come file descriptor 4 in two different processes point to two totally different files(namely File A and File B)? And how can we have File A **two times** in the Open File Table? Shouldn't each file be presented only once?