# file descriptors and /dev/fd

Tags: open-files

Are file descriptors unique across a process, or throughout the whole system.  Because every file seems the use the same descriptor for stdin and stdout.  Is there something special with these? How does stdin and stdout work? I realize the `dev/fd`, is a link to `proc/self/fd`, but how do they all have the same number?

*Edit:*  Even after looking at other processes most of the file descriptors are about the same numbers.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24145/how-can-different-file-descriptors-point-to-the-same-file-in-open-file-table and other questions tagged [tag:file-descriptors].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several things might be confusing here.

Filedescriptors are attached to a file (in the general sense) and are specific to a given process. Filedescriptors are themselves referred to via numeric ids by their associated process, but one file descriptor can have several ids. Example: ids 1 and 2 which are called standard output and standard error usually refers to the same file descriptor.

The symlinks `/proc/pid/fd/x` only provide a hint for what the *x* filedescriptor of process *pid* is linked to. If it's a regular file, the symlink gives its path. But if the filedescriptor is e.g. an inet socket, then the symlink is just broken. In the case of a regular file (or something which has a path like a tty), it's possible to open it, but you would obtain a *different* filedescriptor to the same object.