# How can same fd in different processes point to the same file?

Tags: kernel, open-files, file-descriptors

Say I have *process 1* and *process 2*. Both have a file descriptor corresponding to the integer 4.

In each process however the file descriptor 4 points to a totally different file in the Open File Table of the kernel:

[image]

How is that possible? Isn't a file descriptor supposed to be the index to a record in the Open File Table?

Comment: Good question! My guess is that the file descriptors are translated, so that the fd `4` in both processes are relative to it's own number of open fd's. Fd's `0-2` (stdin,stdout,sdterr) are always opened for a new process and the numbers are not reserved for only that process.

Comment: [related question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24145/how-can-different-file-descriptors-point-to-the-same-file-in-open-file-table)

Comment: @jw013 I thought this sounded familiar. \@Pithikos How is this not a duplicate?

Comment: @Michael Mrozek This is indeed a duplicate. However I reedited the question as I didn't get any good explanation on the old one. (This scheme is also much more relevant to the question.)

Comment: @Pithikos Ok; I'm going to merge that one into this one then. In the future, this is what [bounties](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) are for

Comment: This is a poor diagram - it should show that file descriptor 4 means the _fourth entry_ [well, fifth, it's counted from zero] of the file descriptor table on the left, not an entry which contains a "4". The actual "4" lives in your userspace variable containing the number. The diagram in the other question is much better.

Comment: @Random832 Well if I knew which diagram was correct then I would probably never had made this question.

Comment: If I fork a process and then if I want to redirect the stdout file descriptor of the child, from parent how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The file descriptor, i.e. the `4` in your example, is the index into the process-specific *file descriptor table*, **not** the open file table.  The file descriptor entry itself *contains* an index to an entry in the kernel's global open file table, as well as file descriptor flags.

Comment: For the record, there is only one "file descriptor flag" on most systems, the close-on-exec flag. All other "per-fd" state (including the offset and the access mode) is part of the open file table entry.

Answer (score 31):

Each process has its own file descriptor table. File descriptor 4 in process 1234 points inside process 1234's table. File descriptor 4 in process 5678 points inside process 5678's table. A case you must be familiar with are file descriptors 0, 1 and 2 which for each process are the standard input, standard output and standard error, pointing wherever these were redirected to.

A process can open the same file more than once. This can happen coincidentally, for example when a process's standard output and standard error are redirected to the same terminal or to the same file. The underlying file table entries (e.g. [Linux's `struct file`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.1/include/linux/fs.h#L953)) carry more than information about the file; they also contain opening modes (e.g. read or write) and other state (such as flags, e.g. close-on-exec). For example, a process might have a terminal opened for reading only on file descriptor 0 and that same terminal opened for writing only on file descriptor 2. File tables entries also contain the process's position in the file; a process might want to `lseek` to two different positions in the same file, and so would use `dup` to obtain two handles to that file.

Comment: This isn't entirely correct.  According to the man page / specs, `dup` does an exactly what it says on the tin: both resulting descriptors point to the same file table entry and thus share the same offset.  In order to get 2 different file table entries, I'm pretty sure you need to `open` the file twice.

Comment: @Gilles "File descriptor 4 in process 1234 points inside process 1234's table". Which table do you mean? From what I know the only table in the process is the *File Descriptor Table* where each record points to the kernel's **single** *Open File Table*.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195057/what-is-an-open-file-description/195164#195164 for a more precise description.

Answer (score 9):

Each process has it's own file descriptor table. That's all.

It's all very well described in [UNIX Network Programming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0139498761) by Richard Stevens if you would like to learn it deeply.

Comment: Which table are you referring to?

Comment: file descriptor table

Answer (score 8):

Wouldn't an extra level of indirection fix your problem? ("All problems in computer programming can be solved by an extra level of indirection" - some wise greybeard).  That is, the small integer in each process ends up as an index into a per-process array of kernel-space indexes into the "Open File Table".

Comment: The [source](http://www.dmst.aueb.gr/dds/pubs/inbook/beautiful_code/html/Spi07g.html) *wise greybeard* is likely David Wheeler.  It appears he also said, "*But that usually will create another problem.*" :)

Answer (score 0):

For getting an intuition on why every file descriptor should be indexed on local file descriptor table, one can see the case of [redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) in unix systems. For a process one can redirect its stdout to any other file and thus overloading the file descriptor "1" for that process without altering what that "1" meant for other process. Same holds true for stdin and stderr. Thus there must be a local file descriptor to support such behaviour.