# What exactly is a file offset in lsof output?

Tags: centos, rhel, lsof

I was using `lsof` to track down deleted files that were still taking up space and I realized that I wasn't quite sure what an offset is with respect to a file. `lsof`'s man page was less than helpful in this regard and searching around I couldn't get a clear picture of what it is.

What is a file offset and why is it useful to have that piece of information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The offset is the current position in the file, as maintained by the kernel for a given file description (see the [`lseek(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) and [`open(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) manpages for details).

As to why it's useful in `lsof`'s output, I'm not really sure. It can give some idea of a process's progress through a file, although it won't cover all cases (memory-mapped files won't show offset changes).

Answer (score 6):

[Stephen Kitt's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208900) is close, but not quite correct; if we read [**lseek(2)**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) more carefully, we will see that it actually says (bold mine):

> The **lseek**() function repositions the file offset of the **open file
>   description** associated with the file descriptor *fd* [...]

So, what's an "open file description" and how does it relate to a "file descriptor"?

Well, down in the NOTES section, we find:

> See [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) for a discussion of the relationship between file
>   descriptors, open file descriptions, and files.

Perfect! However, rather than pasting a wall of text from the manpage, I'll just link to [a good answer to "What is an open file description?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195057/what-is-an-open-file-description/195164#195164) that explains the same thing.